# Draw a plot in R as the function varies

Tags: r, function, plot

I have this code named prob.

```
prob<-function(k){
  start=1
  for(i in 1:k-1){
    cumm=start*(1-i/365)
    start=cumm
  }
  return(start)
}
```

Then, I created this function, opp.

```
opp<-function(a){
  1-prob(a)
}
```

Now, I want to plot opp from 1 to 25. 
For example, I want to see `opp(1), opp(2), opp(3), opp(4)...., opp(25)`

I have tried

`plot(opp(a=x),from=1,to=25)`

or

`plot(opp,from=1,to=25)`

or

`plot(1:25,opp[1:25])`

...

none of these work...

so frustrated... please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fix the `opp` function to be vectorized before plotting.

You can just `Vectorize(opp)` for a quick fix:

```
prob<-function(k){
  start=1
  for(i in 1:k-1){
    cumm=start*(1-i/365)
    start=cumm
  }
  return(start)
}

opp<-function(a){
  1-prob(a)
}

vopp <- Vectorize(opp)

vopp(1:25)

#  [1] 0.000000000 0.002739726 0.008204166 0.016355912 0.027135574 0.040462484
#  [7] 0.056235703 0.074335292 0.094623834 0.116948178 0.141141378 0.167024789
# [13] 0.194410275 0.223102512 0.252901320 0.283604005 0.315007665 0.346911418
# [19] 0.379118526 0.411438384 0.443688335 0.475695308 0.507297234 0.538344258
# [25] 0.568699704
```

Alternatively, doing it a more "R" way would be:

```
opp2 <- function(k) 1 - cumprod(1 - (k - 1) / 365)

opp2(1:25)
# [1] 0.000000000 0.002739726 0.008204166 0.016355912 0.027135574 0.040462484
# [7] 0.056235703 0.074335292 0.094623834 0.116948178 0.141141378 0.167024789
# [13] 0.194410275 0.223102512 0.252901320 0.283604005 0.315007665 0.346911418
# [19] 0.379118526 0.411438384 0.443688335 0.475695308 0.507297234 0.538344258
# [25] 0.568699704
```

And both give me this

```
plot(opp2(1:25))
plot(vopp(1:25))
```

[image]